# Adding GeoJSON tile set to an existing map

Tags: layers, style, mapbox

I'm confused on how to add my GeoJSON tileset to an existing map built with a default style. Do I add the GeoJSON by ID or by style? Here is what I'm working with now.

Added .geojson to Tilesets as FCC_States2_4326-7v9iga

```
ID = mmcinnis.crxr86ot
```

Style made with tileset:

```
mapbox://styles/mmcinnis/cjtroguqv0t8s1fqjo9o5rwvy
```

Script:

```
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW1ja...';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        //style: 'mapbox://styles/mmcinnis/cjtroguqv0t8s1fqjo9o5rwvy',
        center: [-99.9, 41.5],
        zoom: 1
    });

    map.on('load', function () {
        map.addSource("fcc-states2-4326", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: "mapbox://styles/mmcinnis/cjtroguqv0t8s1fqjo9o5rwvy"
        })

        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'example',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': "fcc-states2-4326",
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'fill-color': '#088',
                'fill-opacity': 0.8
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: OK, I found some documentation and I think I'm close but the debugger shows 422 (Unknown) map.addSource("fcc-states2-4326", {
                type: "vector",
                url: "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/mmcinnis/mmcinnis.crxr86ot?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibW..."
            })

Comment: Had to add source-layer...  map.addLayer({
                'id': 'mmcinnis.crxr86ot',
                'type': 'fill',
                'source': "fcc-states2-4326",
                "source-layer": "fcc-states2-4326",
                'layout': {},
                'paint': {
                    'fill-color': '#088',
                    'fill-opacity': 0.8
                }
            });

Answer (score 0):

If you're added the data to your custom style in Mapbox Studio, ie. 'mapbox://styles/mmcinnis/cjtroguqv0t8s1fqjo9o5rwvy' then you can just skip addSource and addLayer and use your custom style as the style in the map initialisation.

Otherwise if you want to programatically add a new source and layer to your map, then addSource should be set `type: "vector"` if you're using a Mapbox Tileset ID, or if you want to use `type: "geojson"` you need to pass it either a URL to your GeoJSON file or the JSON object itself.

Comment: I will need the syntax for the addSource addLayer method as my next step in development is to data-join the GeoJSON with SQL query data. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-join/

Comment: I only see the 'id' on the mapbox tileset page, what points at the tileset?        map.on('load', function () {
            map.addSource("fcc-states2-4326", {
                type: "vector",
                data: "What goes here???"
            })

            map.addLayer({
                'id': 'mmcinnis.crxr86ot',
                'type': 'fill',
                'source': "fcc-states2-4326",
                'layout': {},
                'paint': {
                    'fill-color': '#088',
                    'fill-opacity': 0.8
                }
            });
        });

Comment: Simply, in .addSource after type: "vector" what do you use to point to the tileset? All I see is the id? map.addSource("fcc-states2-4326", {
                type: "vector",
                data: "mmcinnis.crxr86ot" 
            })

Comment: Where is the URL defined to the GeoJSON tileset?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I ultimately got to work:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Join local JSON data with vector tile geometries</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='map'>
    </div>
    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW1...';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
            //style: 'mapbox://styles/mmcinnis/cjtroguqv0t8s1fqjo9o5rwvy',
            center: [-99.9, 41.5],
            zoom: 1
        });

        map.on('load', function () { 
            map.addSource("FCC_States2_4326-7v9iga", {
                type: "vector", 
                url: "mapbox://mmcinnis.crxr86ot"
            })
            map.addLayer({ 
                'id': 'fcc-states2-4326', 
                'type': 'fill', 
                'source': "FCC_States2_4326-7v9iga", 
                "source-layer": "FCC_States2_4326-7v9iga",
                'layout': {},
                'paint': { 
                    'fill-color': '#088', 
                    'fill-opacity': 0.8 
            } 
        }); 
        });
    </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```